# Finding offset of a word in a text node in javascript

Tags: javascript

Any ideas how can I get a offset value of a searched word in a text node relative to the whole document?

Comment: Hi Welcome to stackoverflow can you please post you Attempt

Comment: What do you mean by offset value ? The question is too short for anyone to exactly understand what you are asking.. `:)`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the "offset value", especially when "relative to the whole document". An HTML document is represented as a tree. Thus any "offset" will be relative to a branch, or the trunk.

Comment: Hi @mgor3k, welcome to SO. It's recommended to accompany your question with your own idea of the solution and an explanation of why your solution is problematic.

Comment: oh sorry. im not familiar with javascript. The whole text node has a property offsetTop, but I need to find an exact string in that text node and get its offset from the top. I need this for calculating the right page after searching for a word in a WebView in a mobile app (ebook reader).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you need. In the example below the code is searching the word "offset". If the word is found the word is wrapping the word in a span element. Next the methos `getBoundingClientRect` returns the size of the span element and its position relative to the viewport  Please take a look at my code:

```js
let p = document.querySelector(".text");
let text = p.innerHTML;


let new_text =
    text.replace(/(offset)/, function(found) {
      return "<span>" + found + "</span>"
    });

p.innerHTML = new_text;

let thefoundText = document.querySelector("span");
console.log(thefoundText.getBoundingClientRect())
```

```css
span{color:red;}
```

```html
<p class="text">Finding offset of a word in a text node in javascript
</p>
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you really want just do this

```
words.substr(offset, length) // Length means where the word ends in the string
```

I hope i got it right here you go